# How to monitor a UDP specific port/socket?

Tags: freebsd, socket, netstat, udp

I have an application that receives UDP packets at port 5000.

In order to be 100% sure that the application is receiving all packets (for example the RX buffer could be full and some packets could be drop) I would like to monitor the connection at OS level.

I have been told that I can use:

```
% netstat -s -p udp
udp:
        573 datagrams received
        0 with incomplete header
        0 with bad data length field
        0 with bad checksum
        0 with no checksum
        0 dropped due to no socket
        345 broadcast/multicast datagrams undelivered
        0 dropped due to full socket buffers
        0 not for hashed pcb
        228 delivered
        228 datagrams output
        0 times multicast source filter matched
```

Where such information exists, but grouped for all UDP sockets.

Is there any way or workaround to get this information for just UDP port 5000?

FreeBSD 12.1

Comment: figure out where netstat gets its data ... this may help ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33150564/in-linux-where-does-the-netstat-su-command-get-the-statistics

Comment: A Stack Overflow answer about Linux will not be of much help to a question about FreeBSD.

Comment: It does not hurt anyway, I would keep the link for reference.